# Notation for inner product between scalar-valued and vector-valued functions

Tags: functions, notation, vectors, inner-products, projection

Consider $\mathbf{f}:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\left(\phi_k\right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$, where $\phi:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

My intent is to write $\mathbf{f}$ as a projection onto the basis formed by $\phi$:

$$
\mathbf{f}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi_k\mathbf{w}_k,
$$

with $\mathbf{w}_k$ being:

$$
\mathbf{w}_k=\begin{bmatrix}\langle\phi_k,f_1\rangle\\
\langle\phi_k,f_2\rangle\\
\vdots\\
\langle\phi_k,f_n\rangle\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can I compactify this notation somehow, maybe embedding it into the summation? I was thinking about something as $\langle\phi_k,\mathbf{f}\rangle$. As $\phi$ is a scalar function, and $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector function, is it obvious to relate the two notations? Do you have any other suggestions?

Moreover, from the definitions of $\mathbf{f}$ and $\phi$, is it correct to say that $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{C}^n$?